# Selenium Finding Element within Element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I know this question seems to have been asked before, but when I try emulating the responses that worked for others, there is still an issue.

My code is:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tabdocsumtable"]/tbody')      
entries = table.find_elements_by_class('rprt')
```

I am getting

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute
>   'find_element_by_class'

Link to webpage: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=setx%5Bgene%5D

Comment: [How about](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=find_elements) `table.find_elements_by_class_name`? I'll post as an answer if leaving off `_name` was your issue.

Comment: You're right. I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I know how frustrating these things can be, glad that worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the python binding docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=find_elements), it looks like the method for python is `find_elements_by_class_name`.

So this line:

```
entries = table.find_elements_by_class('rprt')
```

should be:

```
entries = table.find_elements_by_class_name('rprt')
```